# Exposing a property setter/getter to dataclass repr/init

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

With the introduction of python dataclasses you can declare your fields on the class and they will show up on the `__init__` by default and you can customize it with `field()`.

Is there a clean way to add a property setter to the list of things that will show up in `__init__`? And the getter to the list of things that show up in `__repr__`?

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    _a: int = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
```

Comment: Properties are *class* attributes, not instance attributes. As something that implements the descriptor protocol, properties exhibit different behavior depending on whether you access them via the class or an instance of the class.

Comment: You can use `a: InitVar[property]` to solve the problem of getting `__init__` to take an argument, but you'd still have to write `__post_init__` to *use* it. It doesn't address the issue of making `__repr__` use `a`, because `a` is not a field.

Comment: Yeah the issue with `InitVar` is that the normalization logic of that field only runs on init and not every time that field is set.

Comment: You still have to define the property; the issue is getting the property treated the same as a field with regards to the auto-generated methods.

Comment: `_a` itself shouldn't really be a field; it's an implementation detail for the property. Everything else in your class should be working with `a`, not `_a` directly, so that's why you need something like a property field. (A term I just made up; they don't exist in dataclass-world.)